Artifactory HA and user plugin scheduled execution
When writing an Artifactory user plugin that contains a scheduled execution, does deploying the plugin on an Artifactory HA installation cause the task to be executed concurrently on all Artifactory nodes when the interval triggers?  Or does Artifactory ensure it runs on only one node when it triggers?

The answer is yes, Artifactory ensures that only one instance of the background task is being picked and processed by only one node/pod in the cluster.

Can you add any documentation/links to your answer?
